# CouchDB cross-domain access from XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: cross-domain, couchdb

Currently, web application need to offer some kind of cross-domain HTTP header to access data on other domain: http://openfontlibrary.org/wiki/Web_Font_linking_and_Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Is there any way to configure CouchDB to support unlimited cross-domain access? (it may use apache httpd internally) I'm using the db in-house purpose only.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead by now and returs a 404 error page.

Comment: @MKroehnert Oh. And it's making me crazy that I cannot even remember what I wanted to do three years ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a CouchDB show function to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

```
function(doc, req) {
  return {
    body : 'whatever',
    headers : {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "\"*\""
    }
  }
}
```

More info on show functions here: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/show.html

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't support POST, PUT and DELETE :( is there a way to support these methods?

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way I found to solve it is by using locally installed **Apache Web Server** with enabled **mod_proxy** module and configured **ProxyPass** directive.

Let start with basic setup

- I have Apache Web Server installed on http://127.0.0.1:8181, not configured yet
- I have CouchDB installed on http://127.0.0.1:5984/
- I have **index.html** deployd on Apache on: http://localhost:8181/couchdb.html.

index.html has the following content

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var http = XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/_all_dbs', true); // ! WE WILL CHANGE THIS LINE
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.debug('it works');
    }
};
http.send(null)
</script>
<head><title>Test Access to CouchDB</title></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If you try it just now it will not work because of the cross domain problem (in this instance ports don't match 8181 != 5984).

How to fix it

- configure Apache (apache_home/conf/httpd.conf)

  - uncomment **`LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so`**
  - uncomment **`LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so`**
  - add **`ProxyPass /couchdb http://127.0.0.1:5984`** (as top level property like ServerAdmin)
  - restart Apache
- modify index.html

  - replace `http.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/_all_dbs', true);` with **`http.open('GET', '/couchdb/_all_dbs', true);`**

Try now and you should see 'it works' output in the javascript console (I used Firebug Console)

Answer (score 4):

CouchDB 1.3 solves this with CORS: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CORS

Comment: Notice for all installing couchdb on debian/ubuntu via package manager. As of today (10-Oct-2014) the version you will get is 1.2 and it does NOT support CORS options. If you want to use them you have to install never version from sources. It took me a bit to realise why my CORS settings did not work, and the reason was I've installed it via apt-get install couchdb and it was version 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

Eonil, I want Cross-Domain access too, but is not supported by CouchDB, 
you can vote for that feature to be implemented here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-431

ps: that feature request has been created on 23/Jul/09 :( I hope they hear us.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it. I've voted up! I think HTTP REST protocol feature is just such a syntactic sugar things. convenient feature should be offered simultaneously. but I don't expect CouchDB people do this because I'm guessing they're doing some kind of business already doesn't need care of regular users. And I recommend you check *OrientDB* also for offering fast, convenient HTTP REST interface. However I've decided to go back to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about OrientDB, it's feature list seems very interesting, In my case I found HTTP REST useful (or required) as I plan to access the db storage from the client browser using jQuery. What I'm founding most frustating about CouchDB is that static views using MapReduce is the only query mechanism!

Answer (score 3):

you should enable [CORS in CouchDB](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CORS) > 1.3. This is as simple as editing your `default.ini` and setting `enable_cors = true` and then modifying `origins` under the `[cors]` section to have the top level urls you need. For example I had to do the following to whitelist my local grunt server.

```
enable_cors = true
[cors]
origins = http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

to fully answer this question though you'd want to set

```
origins = *
```

though this could be argued to be a vulnerability, and you should probably restrict the origins more.

Comment: Notice for all installing couchdb on debian/ubuntu via package manager. As of today (10-Oct-2014) the version you will get is 1.2 and it does NOT support CORS options. If you want to use them you have to install never version from sources. It took me a bit to realise why my CORS settings did not work, and the reason was I've installed it via apt-get install couchdb and it was version 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have solved this is to write a 2 line Rebol wrapper CGI and then ask my Ajax in Jquery to call my CGI instead of the URL for getting data from Couchdb:

```
Rebol [

  {wrapper to overcome cross-domain fetching of data from couchdb}
 ]
print "Content-type: application/json^/"  ;text/plain^/"
print read http://127.0.0.1:5984/syncspace/_design/vals/_view/xxxx?group=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a list that returns JSONp...but still read only support

```
"jsonp": "function(head, req) {
    var row;
    var rows=[];
    while(row = getRow()){
        rows.push(row);
    }
    rj = JSON.stringify({\"rows\" : rows,\"total_rows\":rows.length});
    return req.query.callback+\"(\"+rj+\");\";
}",
```